# Traversing and averaging elements in an array MASM

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, masm

I am in a x86 masm class, and we have a project coming up that I do not understand. The TA and Professor are pretty much useless, I've been trying to get into contact with them for a week and no answer and no office hours. Anyways, I am supposed to calculate the average number of days per month over the span of 15 years. (2000-2015) We are also supposed to factor in leap year.

I wrote the program in C beforehand, and here is my code:

```
main()
{   
    double sum=0;

    int dpm[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int months=0;

    while(j<16)
    {
        while(i<12)
        {
            if(j==0 || j==4 || j==8 || j==12)
            {
                dpm[1]=29;
            }
            sum+=dpm[i];
            dpm[1]=28;
            months++;
            i++;
        }
    j++;
    }
    printf("%.2f",sum/months);
}
```

(I realize using a for-loop would be best here, however while loops are easier to do in asm, so I used a while loop)

I don't understand assembly too well, but here is what I have so far:

```
.DATA

    sum    DWORD 0
    months DWORD 0
    dpm    DWORD 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31
    elm    DWORD 12
    i      WORD  0
    j      WORD  0

.CODE
main

    mov eax, sum            ; move sum to eax
    lea esi, dpm            ; move array to ebx
    mov ecx, elm            ; move no of elements to ecx
    mov ax, j               ; move j to ax
    mov bx, i               ; move i to bx

outterLoop:

    cmp 15, ax              ; compare 15 to i
    jle innerloop           ; jump to inner loop if it is less

innerLoop:

    cmp 11, bx              ; compare 11 to j
    jle checkLeap           ; jump to checkleap if it is less
    inc ax                  ; incremement j

checkLeap:

    cmp 0, bx               ; if j is 0
    je leap                 ; go to leap year function
    cmp 4, bx
    je leap
    cmp 8, bx
    je leap
    cmp 12, bx
    je leap
    jne updates             ; if not, go to updates fn

leap:

    add esi, 4              ; go to second element in array "february"
    mov 29, esi             ; make feb 29 instead of 28

updates:

    add eax, [esi]          ; add element to sum
    add esi, 4              ; increment array

    ; inc months

    mov                     ; here I would make second element of array 28

    inc bx                  ; increment i
```

I do not know if I am on the right track, and would like guidance, advice. Thank you

Comment: This belongs in CodeReview, not on SO.

Comment: Does the assembly code work as intended? **If so**, @RLH's comment is a way of saying [codereview.se] may be a better place to ask. If not, then your question is not very clear, Stack Overflow (SO) likes clearly presented specific programming issues. Cheers!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the results you expect and the results you're getting; or include the errors you get when you assemble the code. Basically, assembly it, run it, and let us know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Is your outer loop suppose to be i? not j?

Comment: Adding to what @BobJarvis said, a few points about your c: 1) What value does `i` have on the second time thru the `j` loop?  Since you never reset it... 2) Modifying dpm[1] seems inefficient.  Why not just say `if (j == ...) sum++`? 3) I'd declare `sum` as an int, then assign it to a float for the division after the loop.  That will be easier to convert to asm.  And re the asm: What is with `jle innerloop`?  In asm, if the jump is not taken, it will proceed to the next statement.  Since the next statement is the label for innerloop, this `jle` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing with an immediate value you need to put the number last. (Correct it 7 times)

```
cmp ax, 15           ; compare 15 to i
```

To change the length of february in the list use

```
mov dword [esi], 29  ; make feb 29 instead of 28
```

Same thing to reset it

```
mov dword [esi], 28  ; here I would make second element of array 28
```

Since you have put your **j** index in the AX register you need to place the sum in a register different from EAX. Remember that AX is just the low 16 bits of EAX.

The next code needs an additional jump. Now it ALWAYS performs *innerLoop*

```
 cmp ax,15       ; compare 15 to i
 jle innerloop   ; jump to inner loop if it is less

innerLoop:
```

Answer (score 0):

*this code is working and giving correct output in edx register.*

> comment below if you want me to add comments to this code.

**i implemented your logic with necessary changes, the thing is you are implementing that incorrectly**

```
Include irvine32.inc
.data
; (31==1Fh)(30==1Eh)(28==1Ch)(29==1Dh)
dpm dword   1Fh,1Ch,1Fh,1Eh,1Fh,1Eh,1Fh,1Fh,1Eh,1Fh,1Eh,1Fh
countj  dword   ?
temp    dword   ?
temp1   dword   ?
.code
Main Proc
;   [instr] [destor opp1]   [addtio instr]  [source orOpp2] ;comment
mov ecx,                15      ;intializing to max value of j
mov esi,        offset      dpm     ;storing offset of dpm to esi
mov edx,        0               ;intializing sum to 0
mov ebx,        0               ;intializing counter to 0
mov eax,        0               ;intializing counter to 0
loopj:                              ;loop of j
mov countj,             ecx     ;storing count of j
mov ecx,                12      ;intializing to max value of i
loopi:                              ;loop of i  
inc ebx                 
mov eax,                countj
;start of if statement:
cmp eax,                1       ;jump if j is 1
je  IfJConTrueStart                 
cmp eax,                5       ;jump if j is 5
je  IfJConTrueStart                 
cmp eax,                9       ;jump if j is 9
je  IfJConTrueStart                 
cmp eax,                13      ;jump if j is 13
je  IfJConTrueStart                 
                        ;29
JConMid:
call    dumpregs
mov temp1,              edx     
mov eax,                ecx
mov temp,       type        dpm     
mul temp
add esi,                eax     
sub esi,                temp        
call    dumpregs        
mov edx,                temp1
add edx,                [esi]
call    dumpregs        
sub esi,                eax 
add esi,                temp
call    dumpregs                    
JConEnd:
loop    loopi                       
mov ecx,                countj      
loop    loopj           
jmp skipIfJConTrue                      
IfJConTrueStart:        
cmp ecx,                2
je  IfJConTrueMid
jmp JConMid
IfJConTrueMid:
add edx,                1Dh
jmp JConEnd
skipIfJConTrue:             
call    dumpregs                
Exit
Main endp
End main
```